# Is there a unification space such that this convolution make sense?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

By the definition of convolution $$h(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)g(x-t)dt$$ this integral can make sense if we take $f, g\in L^1$ or $f\in L^1$ and $g\in L^\infty$ or $g\in L^1$ and $f\in L^\infty$ and so on.  Is there a unification space such that this convolution make sense?

Comment: What is a unification space?

Comment: and what is $f/g$ or $g/f$?

Comment: A enough large set such that this concolution make sense!

Comment: For instance, you can view the convolution operation as a map $$* : L^1 \times L^\infty \to L^1, \quad (f, g) \mapsto f * g.$$ Is this the "unification space" you want?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I will think it carefully later.

Comment: More generally, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality